# MAMP: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' Windows 10

Tags: php, dll, mamp

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' (tried: W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext\php_php_intl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
Here are the files list in the directory:

W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext>dir
     Volume in drive W is WEBSERVER
     Volume Serial Number is 2A6E-355C

```
 Directory of W:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.2.14\ext

Вт 31.12  11:20    <DIR>          .
Вт 31.12  11:20    <DIR>          ..
Чт 20.06  13:16            50 688 php_apcu.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16            70 656 php_bz2.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16           459 776 php_curl.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16            57 856 php_exif.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16         5 019 648 php_fileinfo.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16            42 496 php_ftp.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16         1 151 488 php_gd2.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16            49 152 php_gettext.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16           237 568 php_gmp.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16           221 696 php_imagick.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16           814 592 php_imap.dll
Чт 20.06  13:16           327 168 php_intl.dll
```

W10 Apache/2.2.31 MAMP 4.1.1

I try to add PATH Variable but that doesn't work form me. 
My solution was to copy dll and set this name "php_php_intl.dll.dll" finaly I have in the same directory:

(C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\ext)

- php_php_intl.dll.dll
- php_intl.dll

that's works for me.

Comment: Is there a question here? `The specified module could not be found.` might indicate that the module is compiled for a different version of PHP than the version you're trying to load it in - not that the `dll` file is not being found.